# Using image from private docker registry in pulumi on ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, pulumi

I want to use pulumi to set up ECS with an image from a private docker registry (GitLab). Is there a way to specify the secret in the container defintion?

I'm trying to set up a new ECS cluster (awsx.ecs.Cluster) with a Service (awsx.ecs.EC2Service) running a Task with a container (awsx.ecs.Container). The image for the container is stored in a Gitlab private docker registry.

In the AWS console I would've created a Task with a container and selected `Private repository authentication`. This allows setting an arn to a secret in secrets manager containing credentials as described in [Private Registry Authentication for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html).

I haven't found a way to set this in pulumi though.

Comment: you want to add image to ecs with pulumi after creating ecs?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new ECS cluster with a docker image from an external private docker registry and am looking for a way to provide credentials for the registry. I've edited the question to provide further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you would need to do it like you [normally would in kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Create a docker registry secret (set its type to `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`) and make pod reference that secret, so add `imagepullsecrets` to pod spec.

FOr more details consult the link I've referenced

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find the option to add the secret to the task's container in Pulumi.

Comment: just add it to spec like you normally would, its just a reference to a secret in container definition

Comment: You're right, I just added `repositoryCredentials` to the `awsx.ecs.Container` definition and it was added to the task's container. Not sure why it didn't work at first. Thanks for the help.